# Decorator pattern on Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, decorator

I'm creating 2 `Fragment` base classes and each of them has methods provided by 2 `interfaces` respectively. Now I want a third `Fragment` with methods from both interfaces **by using the decorator pattern**. Since you can **only use a empty constructor on a subclassed `Fragment`**, how can I accomplish this?

PS: once again, *using the decorator pattern*.

Comment: Can we talk about this over chat? I think talking through here will lead to a long series of comments.

Comment: Yes sure, let's go over chat

Comment: I do not see you in chat

Comment: sorry, this is my first time being in chat, can't find where to create it

Comment: Any conclusion on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

as you said you need to have an empty constructor. There is a reason for that, because the framework will instantiate the fragment in some cases (inflation from layout, loading after configuration change).

You could create an another constructor in addition to the default no-arg one, but the passed arguments would loose if the framework were recreate your fragment (because it uses the no-arg constructor). So your decorator would be instantiated without the fragment to decorate.

This way:

```
newInstance(Fragment toDecorate){
   Bundle b = new Bundle();
   b.putFragment???
```

would fail also, since you cannot serialize a Fragment to a Bundle, and again, because the framework manages them.

The only way that I can think of is subclassing that is actually an alternative to the Decorator pattern. What would you gain by using Decorator compared to subclassing? Do you really need the ability to add/modify functionality of a fragment at runtime?

PS.: This is not really an answer, since you have said you want a solution with Decorator pattern. It's a suggestion on considering subclassing as an alternative.

Comment: Yeah, seems like I won't be able to decorate. It's a shame cause what I really need is multiple-inheritance. Not just multiple-interface cause of defined methods.